# Using reduce, from an array of objects, create a set of elements inside the objects' array attributes

Tags: javascript, set, reduce

Given the following array:

```
foos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    bar: ['a','b','c']
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: ['a','b','d']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: ['a','c']
  },
]
```

Using `reduce`, how can I achieve the following?:

`bars == ['a','b','c','d']`

I've tried:

`foo.reduce((bars, foo) => bars.add(foo.bar), new Set())`

But it results in a set of objects:

`Set { {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'd'}{0: 'a', 1: 'c'}}`

And:

`foos.reduce((bars, foo) => foo.bar.forEach(bar => bars.add(bar)), new Set())`

But the `forEach` has no access to the `bars` set.

Comment: Use map inside reduce, you are pushing bar array into set, that is pushing whole bar object into set

Comment: You need to loop through `foo.bar` and add them individually to `bars.add()`. And return the `bars` set from the `reduce`

Comment: Or to shorten it: `new Set( foos.flatMap(f => f.bar) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) inside your [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). You could just reduce all `bar` arrays into a single one and pass that to your Set constructor.

```js
const foos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    bar: ['a','b','c']
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: ['a','b','d']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: ['a','c']
  },
];

const bars = new Set(foos.reduce((all, foo) => [...all, ...foo.bar], []));

console.log(...bars);
```

With [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const foos = [
  {
    id: 0,
    bar: ['a','b','c']
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: ['a','b','d']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: ['a','c']
  },
];

const bars = new Set(foos.flatMap(foo => foo.bar));

console.log(...bars);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `concat` the `bar` property in the accumulator, and use `.filter` method to make the values unique:

```js
const foos = [{
    id: 0,
    bar: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    bar: ['a', 'b', 'd']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bar: ['a', 'c']
  },
];

const bars = foos
  .reduce((acc, itm) => acc.concat(itm.bar), [])
  .filter((i, x, s) => s.indexOf(i) === x);

console.log(...bars);
```